# MySQL 500 million rows table in select query with join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing, subquery

I'm concerned about the performance of the query below once the tables are fully populated. So far it's under development and performs well with dummy data.

The table "adress_zoo" will contain about 500 million records once fully populated. "adress_zoo" table looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE `adress_zoo` 
     ( `adress_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `zoo_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
     UNIQUE KEY `pk` (`adress_id`,`zoo_id`), 
     KEY `adress_id` (`adress_id`) ) 
     ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The other tables will contain maximum 500 records each.

The full query looks like this:

```
  SELECT a.* FROM jos_zoo_item AS a 
  JOIN jos_zoo_search_index AS zsi2 ON zsi2.item_id = a.id 
  WHERE a.id IN (   

     SELECT r.id FROM ( 

        SELECT zi.id AS id, Max(zi.priority) as prio 
        FROM jos_zoo_item AS zi 
        JOIN jos_zoo_search_index AS zsi ON zsi.item_id = zi.id 
        LEFT JOIN jos_zoo_tag AS zt ON zt.item_id = zi.id 
        JOIN jos_zoo_category_item AS zci ON zci.item_id = zi.id 
        **JOIN adress_zoo AS az ON az.zoo_id = zi.id** 

        WHERE 1=1 
        AND ( (zci.category_id != 0 AND ( zt.name != 'prolong' OR zt.name is NULL)) 
        OR (zci.category_id = 0 AND zt.name = 'prolong') ) 
        AND zi.type = 'telefoni' 
        AND zsi.element_id = '44d3b1fd-40f6-4fd7-9444-7e11643e2cef' 
        AND zsi.value = 'Small' 
        AND zci.category_id > 15 
        **AND az.adress_id = 5** 

        GROUP BY zci.category_id ) AS r 
  ) 

  AND a.application_id = 6 
  AND a.access IN (1,1) 
  AND a.state = 1 
  AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-06-07 07:51:26') 
  AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-06-07 07:51:26') 
  AND zsi2.element_id = '1c3cd26e-666d-4f8f-a465-b74fffb4cb14' 

  GROUP BY a.id 
  ORDER BY zsi2.value ASC
```

The query will usually return about 25 records.

Based on your experience, will this query perform acceptable (respond within say 3 seconds)?
What can I do to optimise this?

As adviced by @Jack I ran the query with EXPLAIN and got this:

[image: MySQL EXPLAIN output]

Comment: Off topic: this question will be a great reference material the next time somebody asks "will MySQL perform well with my huge 100k-record table?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is an important limiter:

```
az.adress_id = 5
```

MySQL will limit the table to only those records where `adress_id` matches *before* joining it with the rest of the statement, so it will depend on how big you think that result set might be.

Btw, you have a `UNIQUE(adress_id, zoo_id)` and a separate `INDEX`. Is there a particular reason? Because the first part of a spanning key can be used by MySQL to select with as well.

What's also important is to use `EXPLAIN` to understand how MySQL will "attack" your query and return the results. See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: Hi @Jack,

az.adress_id = X will return about 225 records.

Ok, so I can drop the second index then, great!

What about innodb vs. myisam in this case?

Comment: @user1441607 okay, I've updated my answer to include a link to MySQL's `EXPLAIN` feature.

Comment: Thanks again! I ran it with explain and it seems to use keys where it could? Posted a screen shot in the original post.

Comment: So I guess this could work then? I'm not experienced in how MySQL performs when it comes to larger tables...

What about minimum disk size and RAM? Perhaps another question already asked?

Comment: @user1441607 Tuning your MySQL server to deal with these data sizes is another topic altogether; but it's best to deal with that as the data grows ... say, you add half of the total data inside and see how it goes; if there's a performance issue, you can start asking / looking around :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid subquery you can try to rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT a.* FROM jos_zoo_item AS a 
  JOIN jos_zoo_search_index AS zsi2 ON zsi2.item_id = a.id 
  INNER JOIN 
  (   
     SELECT ** distinct ** r.id FROM ( 

        SELECT zi.id AS id, Max(zi.priority) as prio 
        FROM jos_zoo_item AS zi 
        JOIN jos_zoo_search_index AS zsi ON zsi.item_id = zi.id 
        LEFT JOIN jos_zoo_tag AS zt ON zt.item_id = zi.id 
        JOIN jos_zoo_category_item AS zci ON zci.item_id = zi.id 
        **JOIN adress_zoo AS az ON az.zoo_id = zi.id** 

        WHERE 1=1 
        AND ( (zci.category_id != 0 AND ( zt.name != 'prolong' OR zt.name is NULL)) 
        OR (zci.category_id = 0 AND zt.name = 'prolong') ) 
        AND zi.type = 'telefoni' 
        AND zsi.element_id = '44d3b1fd-40f6-4fd7-9444-7e11643e2cef' 
        AND zsi.value = 'Small' 
        AND zci.category_id > 15 
        **AND az.adress_id = 5** 

        GROUP BY zci.category_id ) AS r 
  ) T
    on a.id = T.id
  where 
  AND a.application_id = 6 
  AND a.access IN (1,1) 
  AND a.state = 1 
  AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-06-07 07:51:26') 
  AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-06-07 07:51:26') 
  AND zsi2.element_id = '1c3cd26e-666d-4f8f-a465-b74fffb4cb14' 

  GROUP BY a.id 
  ORDER BY zsi2.value ASC
```

This approach don't perform subquery for each candidate row. Performance may be increased only if `T` is calculated in few milliseconds.

Comment: I will test this "tweak" once all data is available to me. Thanks @danihp for your input.